# Is there a word to describe someone good at explaining complex topics?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Title says it all. What adjective could be used to describe a person who is good at explaining complex topics?

Answer (score 4):

You could call the person a *perspicuous* teacher.

> **Perspicuous** *adjective*
>   1.1 Able to give an account or express an idea clearly.
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/perspicuous)

Here's an example in use, admittedly from 1871, a long time ago:

> For a period of thirty years Dr. Dyce practised in Aberdeen, enjoying the reputation of a distinguished and assiduous cultivator of obstetric science, a perspicuous teacher, a successful practitioner, and a man of kindly and humane disposition.
>   [- pp20,21, obsterical transactions](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=PnQFAAAAQAAJ&rdid=book-PnQFAAAAQAAJ&rdot=1)

Answer (score 3):

A *natural teacher*.  Or, since you asked for an adjective,

*pedagogical*
(Noun form *pedagogue*)

If you'll accept a phrase,

She's good at *boiling things down.*

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - I appreciate your effort in cleaning up my answer and adding a definition.  But I took it out because it felt all wrong.  To me (and maybe I'm old-fashioned) there is no dull or negative feeling to the word *pedagogue*.  Unfortunately the only definition I could find that supports my interpretation of this word was the Learner's Dictionary, and I had some trouble understanding the formatting of the information on the page, so I wasn't even sure they supported my view.

Comment: It's your answer, do as you like, however, if, as you say, most dictionaries disagree with your personal definition then it may be that most people would disagree with you.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - I guess you understand that the definition you added to my answer doesn't exactly support my answer?  Anyway, I'm not sure if it's a generational thing or that my usage of the word has been contaminated by my second language, Spanish.  But for me, *pedagogue* has no negative connotations, in fact quite the opposite.  I guess the problem with compound answers (such as mine to this question) is that it's hard to know which of my suggestions triggered any upvotes the answer received.  But it seems so messy to write three separate answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/popularize) offers as one definition of "popularize" the following: "to make (something that is difficult or complicated) simpler and easier to understand for the average person".  A person who does this or possesses this ability is often called a "popularizer".  (It is true, of course, that such a person may be referred to by some experts whose arcana have been exposed or, occasionally, actually misrepresented by the simplification, as a "*mere* popularizer".  They may say this with a sniff and a tone of distinct disapproval. The word is not inherently pejorative, but may be used pejoratively, depending upon context.

Answer (score 0):

How about **simplifier**?

A **simplifier** is one who **simplifies**. From *The American Heritage Dictionary*:

> [**simplify**](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=simplify&submit.x=44&submit.y=26): to make simple or simpler, as:
>
> ```
>  a. To reduce in complexity or extent 
>
>  b. To reduce to fundamental parts  
>
>  c. To make easier to understand
> ```

A person who is good at simplifying complex topics is good at making them easier to understand and therefore explain.

Answer (score 0):

Check if these work for you: ***elucidator, enlightener, illuminator***

ODO:

> **[elucidate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elucidate)** 
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Make (something) clear; explain:
>
> work such as theirs will help to elucidate this matter
>
> [WITH CLAUSE]: in what follows I shall try to elucidate what I believe
>   the problems to be
>
> Derivative: 
>   **elucidator**
>   *NOUN*
>
> Lippmann's popularity as a daily elucidator of world-events soon grew
>   nationwide, and his column was last week being syndicated in 160 U. S.
>   and Canadian newspapers of assorted political persuasion.
>
> **[enlighten](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enlighten?q=enlightener#enlighten__16)**
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **1** Give (someone) greater knowledge and understanding about a subject or situation:
>
> Christopher had not enlightened Francis as to their relationship
>
> Perhaps Professor George could enlighten me on the subject.
>
> Derivative: 
>   **enlightener**
>   *NOUN*
>
> True, he has ceased calling himself an artist in interviews,
>   preferring to be regarded as an enlightener and inventor, as a
>   scientist.
>
> **[illuminate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/illuminate?q=illuminator#illuminate__17)** *VERB*
>
> **3** (usually as adjective illuminating) Help to clarify or explain:
>
> a most illuminating discussion
>
> Derivative: **illuminator** *NOUN*
>
> This book was the work of an entire team of illuminators and scribes
>   working to a well-tried formula.

Answer (score 0):

They are lucid. They elucidate.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lucid) gives as the second and third definitions:

> 2
> : having full use of one's faculties : SANE
> 3
> : clear to the understanding : INTELLIGIBLE

Comment: This may be correct, but to be an answer, it requires that "lucid" be authoritatively defined